# Prevent cross origin access to server and logout the user

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to block referrals from other domains to my Codeigniter project.

here is my code

```
if( !isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) === -1 ) {
     $this->session->unset_userdata('id');
     redirect('Main');

  }
```

this code prevents direct URL access to the App and logs the user out, but does not block from another domain. whats the best way to do it?

Comment: You cannot log out a user from another domain.

Comment: actually my goal is not log out user from another domain. I want to check if the referral is from another domain then log out my user from my domain not the referral.

Comment: Well, You can prevent cross-origin access by adding configs to your webserver (Apache or ngnix)

Comment: This code is not even valid. What is is supposed to do? !isset will never be -1.